# Really short citations with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I'm working on a document with an 8 page limit and by no means it's gonna fit a whole list of citations, and I'm looking for a way to have really short citations inline (i.e. no reference list afterwards). Something like

```
... this has been studied in (Smith et. al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 100, 123456 (2012)) ...
```

I'm quite flexible about the particular style, although something based of revtex4 would be nice. Most of my references are journal articles, and the few books I have, I can put by hand if that simplifies things.

I'm trying with package bibentry, but still not manage to find a style that fits my needs. Any ideas? For instance, I need "et al" whenever there is more than one author, no first name initials, no publication title. I need journal abbreviations (although I think this is a separate issue).

Any help will be very appreciated...

Thx

Comment: Two comments: `biblatex` is probably the way to go; and you probably should give a better example of the spec you need in case the person who wants to answer doesn't know the basics of whatever (physics?) style you're loosely basing your document on.  (Will, e.g., all references be to journal articles?  That would make it much easier to implement....)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a biblatex solution. It doesn't need Biber (though of course it will work with it). It's not intended as a polished solution such as one might put together for a full style: it assumes your requirements apply: just books and articles; no bibliography. It allows you to use `\cite` and `\parencite`.

I wasn't sure how to deal with post notes. In the end I've slotted them into the middle of the citations, before the year.

I wasn't sure how to deal with repeated citations; as it is, I've just left them as is, but not repeated the year -- on the basis that you are trying to save space! It's probably simple enough, though, that you can pretty much understand what it's doing and fiddle with the details yourself.

(Don't treat this as an endorsement of this sort of citation system! But needs must, and it's quite a nice demonstration of the flexibility of Biblatex.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{smith,
  author = {Smith and others},
  journaltitle = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {100},
  pages  = {123--456},
  date   = {2012},
}
@BOOK{jones,
  author = {Jones, Arthur},
  title  = {Something about physics},
  date   = {2011},
  publisher = {Dont Print Me},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex, citetracker=true]{biblatex}

% For compression, we just give the *first* page of an article
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
  \mkfirstpage*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
               or test {\iftoggle{postnoteprinted}}}
  {}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\space at\space}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{pagination}}
               or test {\iffieldequalstr{pagination}{page}}}
    {\printfield[default]{postnote}}
    {\printfield{postnote}}
 \global\toggletrue{postnoteprinted}}}


\newtoggle{postnoteprinted}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\togglefalse{postnoteprinted}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{article}}
                  or test {\ifentrytype{book}} }
     {\DeclareFieldAlias{journaltitle}{default}%
      \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}:abbrv}}
     {{\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
         \setunit{\addspace}}
        {\printnames{labelname}%
         \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article:abbrv}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{labelname}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{bracketedyear}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book:abbrv}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{bracketedyear}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Always uses parentheses, because that was what the
% example showed. \mkbibparens would be better IMO.
\newbibmacro{bracketedyear}{%
 \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext{(\printfield{year})}}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

Parenthetical citation: \parencite{smith}. Repeated \parencite[125]{smith}

Citation to a book: \cite[456]{jones}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow!! this is amazing! Thank you soooo very much for your help! I will implement this solution ASAP and let you know the outcome, but I thank you in advance for your time and dedication.

Comment: Ok, here's the outcome. Either the compiler asks me to rerun bibtex, and I get the tagname in boldface instead of the actual citation, or doesn't compile at all

Comment: Make sure you have changed addbibresource to point to you bib file. Just before begin document.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the example verbatim. I also tried changing the addbibresource to point to my database, to no avail... I've also tried to remove the backslash from \begin{filecontents}{\ and from addbibresource. (I'm on OSX, in case that matters)... No success.  Amazingly, when it does complain I can ignore the errors, just hit enter 2 times and... voila! I get the desired output.

Comment: In fact, not the exact desired output is produced, but an asterisk suspiciously appears in front of the volume number, precisely at the two citations that gave error (the first and second, so the error should be within the article:abbrv driver

Comment: OK, I've reduced the problem to the DeclareFieldFormat line. If I comment that out, it compiles, but the output is not exactly what I want...

Comment: The posted code compiles without error on my Mac, which is running the most recent TeXlive, with Biblatex fully updated to v. 2.0. Could you check that you have up-to-date Biblatex packages; there was a change which introduced `\mkfirstpage` relatively recently (within the last year), and that could be the problem.